# identify when user switch between Automatic and manual date & time change

Tags: android, android-date

I want to identify when user has switched to `Automatic date & time` for that i have tried to catch `Intent.ACTION_TIME_CHANGED` intent , which fires twice in case of `Automatic date & time`. But when we change time manually `Intent.ACTION_TIME_CHANGED` fires only once.

i have tried to identify by using autoTimeCalled static variable and now i want to identify when user has changed date manually.

`public static boolean isAutoTimeCalled= false`

```
if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_TIME_CHANGED)){

    autoTimeCalled++;
    if( autoTimeCalled ==2 ){

        Log.e("AUTO" , autoTimeCalled+"");                  
        autoTimeCalled =0;
        isAutoTimeCalled = true;

    }       
}
```

can anyone suggest me the better approach to bifurcate between manual and auto time operations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fetch value in your receiver:

```
android.provider.Settings.Global.getInt(getContentResolver(), android.provider.Settings.Global.AUTO_TIME, 0);
```

It will tell you current settings. It is for API 17 and above.

For lower API

```
android.provider.Settings.System.getInt(getContentResolver(), android.provider.Settings.System.AUTO_TIME, 0);
```